# How to get the NSWindow * for a java Window

Tags: java, macos, nswindow

If I have a Java `Window` object, what's the easiest way, possibly calling Mac-specific supplementary APIs, JNA, or JNI, to get the `NSWindow *` corresponding to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Apple still supports this anymore, [but you *should* be able to get the "`NSView`" inside a window](http://www.sourcecodebrowser.com/libnb-platform-java/6.7.1/classcom_1_1apple_1_1eawt_1_1_cocoa_component.html).  And once you have that, you should be able to get the parent window:

```
import com.apple.eawt.CocoaComponent;

@Override
native public long createNSViewLong();
```